# PHP FTP special characters in filename - can't get modified date

Tags: php, character-encoding, ftp

Using PHP to download files via FTP.

I have no control over the server file names.

i use `ftp_nlist` to get the files in a directory but when I use the same file name to get modified date i get -1 (wrong file name) as result.

`ftp_mdtm` fails only on file names with special characters (such as the German a or e)

```
$list = ftp_nlist($ftpconn, FTP_PCPATH);
foreach($list as $file){
        $src_file = FTP_PCPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
        $md = ftp_mdtm($ftpconn, $src_file);
        if($md == -1){
            echo $src_file . ": " . $md . "\n";
        }
    }
```

This will print all the file names with special characters and a -1 result.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a unicode support problem. PHP has supported unicode (mostly) for a while now. Does your FTP server have BINARY mode turned on, or does it perhaps not support or not activated unicode support?

What happens when you use terminal to FTP to this server and then attempt to perform operations on the files with special characters in them?